# What is the meaning of “Better than the Bourgeois.”?

Tags: dialogue, columbo

I’m an  English language learner.

In *Columbo*, in the first scene of the episode “Short Fuse,” Roddy McDowall as Roger, making a cigar box bomb, says, “Better than the Bourgeois.” What does it imply? I have no idea at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=columbo-1971&episode=s01e08 the line is actually

> Better than the Borgias

The Borgia were a medieval dynasty in competition with the Medici, and reputed to have included murder amongst their various machinations for power - in such a way that their involvement could not be proven.

Roger is trying to prevent the sale of the family business,  and also prevent some rather nasty secrets about his past behavior. He's comparing his own machinations with that of the Borgia.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Now I get the expression.